# Read/parse a ABNF grammar with tags in C++ from a file

Tags: c++, parsing, tags, grammar, abnf

I have a file which contains a ABNF Grammar with tags like in this simplified example:

```
$name = Bertha {userID=013} | Bob {userID=429} | ( Ben | Benjamin ) {userID=265};
$greet = Hi | Hello | Greetings;

$S = $greet $name;
```

Now the task is to obtain the userID by parsing a given sentence for this grammar. For example, parsing the sentence

```
Greetings Bob
```

should give us the userID 429. The grammars have to be read in at runtime because they can change between runs.

My approach for now is the following:

1. parse the grammar into one or multiple trees, putting the tags at the leaves or nodes they belong to
2. parse the sentence with this/those tree(s) to construct a tree which creates the given sentence(I'm thinking about using Earley for this)
3. use this tree to obtain the tags (unlike in the example, there will be multiple different tags in such a tree)

   My question is, are there any software components that I can use or at least modify to solve this task? Especially steps 1 and 2 seem to be quite generic (1. reading a ABNF grammar into a C++ internal representation (e.g. trees); 2. Early-algorithm (or something like that) working with the internal representation from 1.) and writing a complete, fault-proof ABNF parser for step 1 will be a really time consuming task for me.

I know that VoiceXML grammars work like this, but i was unable to find a parser for them. Basically all I could find were parser generators which will generate C++ code for a single grammar, which is not practical for me because the grammars are not known at compile time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2001 I wrote a C++ library that will generate a parser from rules specified at run-time.  It is available on [SourceForge as project BuildParse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/buildparse/) with a LGPL license.  I've used it in a couple of other projects, and I updated it to work with C++ as of 2009. If it doesn't matter if the parser is fast, it might work for you or save you some work rolling your own.

Basically, you'd need a parser to parse your grammar into the data structures that buildparse uses (you can use buildparse for that as well) and then run the buildparse parser generator to generate a something that can recognize tokens.